# How to emulate 4-bit integer in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to emulate overflow behavior of unsigned 4-bit integers, like this:

```
>>> x, y = Int4(10), Int4(9)
>>> x + y
Int4(3)
>>> x * y
Int4(10)
```

Inheritance of builtin `int` seems to work. Is it possible to implement `Int4` class without overriding operator methods like `__add__`?

Comment: Where did you get the `Int4` class from? And you you mean *"emulate"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I don't think such a class exists yet; I think the question is about how to create it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, subclassing `int` will not automatically re-use the type when applying arithmetic to it:

```
>>> class Int4(int):
...     def __new__(cls, i):
...         return super(Int4, cls).__new__(cls, i & 0xf)
... 
>>> x, y = Int4(10), Int4(9)
>>> x + y
19
>>> type(x + y)
<type 'int'>
```

You *have* to override the `__add__`, etc. methods to cast back to `Int4()` when you do this.

If you only ever want to support the type itself (e.g. not support converting other numeric types in the process), then you could can generate most of these:

```
from functools import wraps

class Int4(int):
    def __new__(cls, i):
        return super(Int4, cls).__new__(cls, i & 0xf)

def add_special_method(cls, name):
    mname = '__{}__'.format(name)
    @wraps(getattr(cls, mname))
    def convert_to_cls(self, other):
        bound_original = getattr(super(cls, self), mname)
        return type(self)(bound_original(other))
    setattr(cls, mname, convert_to_cls)

for m in ('add', 'sub', 'mul', 'floordiv', 'mod', 'pow',
          'lshift', 'rshift', 'and', 'xor', 'or'):
    add_special_method(Int4, m)
    add_special_method(Int4, 'r' + m)  # reverse operation
```

This produces methods that *always* return the type of `self` from arithmetic special methods; this'll allow for further subclassing of `Int4` as well.

Demo:

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> class Int4(int):
...     def __new__(cls, i):
...         return super(Int4, cls).__new__(cls, i & 0xf)
... 
>>> def add_special_method(cls, name):
...     mname = '__{}__'.format(name)
...     @wraps(getattr(cls, mname))
...     def convert_to_cls(self, other):
...         bound_original = getattr(super(cls, self), mname)
...         return type(self)(bound_original(other))
...     setattr(cls, mname, convert_to_cls)
... 
>>> for m in ('add', 'sub', 'mul', 'floordiv', 'mod', 'pow',
...           'lshift', 'rshift', 'and', 'xor', 'or'):
...     add_special_method(Int4, m)
...     add_special_method(Int4, 'r' + m)  # reverse operation
... 
>>> x, y = Int4(10), Int4(9)
>>> x + y
3
>>> x * y
10
```

Comment: This code is not so readable. Type `import this` and read the 7th line.

Comment: @ciuak: I am *very* familiar with the Zen, thanks. I am also *Dutch*.

Comment: @ciuak Eeeh... This code is readable, respects PEP8, use Python class methods intelligently, and this solution is far away better than yours.

Comment: And yes, I don't think you can blame Martijn about the Zen of Python. Look his profile next time :-)

Comment: Ok, but that code still can be made in a clean and _very_ readable form. The asker may not fully understand the code you made

Comment: And also, I said about the **7th**, not **8th** line.

Comment: @ciuak: the problem here is that to make the generated methods more readable, you have to produce nested functions instead, which would make the method a lot more verbose indeed.

Comment: I realized that we can just normally work on ints and cap them every time we use it.

Comment: @ciuak: sure, we can just use regular ints and apply `& 0xf` to them after the operation. But that isn't the point of the question, is it.

Comment: Also, I used some while loops to cap the integer, but it's not good when you perform calculations like 2^15.

Comment: @ciuak: `&` is binary AND, `0xf` is hexadecimal for `0b1111` binary, 16 decimal; it masks the integer value to remove anything that doesn't fit in 4 bits.

Comment: @ciuak: So why not use that?

Comment: Because I was so stupid to not include it. (forgot to use the & operator)

Comment: @eryksun: I caved, and used `functools.wraps`. `__qualname__` is now the original, could perhaps be improved to be `'{}.{}'.format(cls.__name__, mname)`.

Comment: @eryksun: I am wondering: should I be naughty and use `__class__` as the local name in `add_special_method` just so I can use the argument-less `super()` call?

Comment: @eryksun: whadayathink? Improvement? It makes it Python 3 specific, but it *is* a little neater.

Comment: @eryksun: nah, I'll revert. It's more about being too clever than that it makes an actual difference here.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the `__add__` method is a good idea, because you can make your calculations look clearly. `Int4(4) + Int4(7)` looks better than `Int4(4).addTo(Int4(7))` (or something like this).
Here is the code that could help you:

```
class Int4:
  def __init__(self, num): # initialising
    self.num = self.cap(num)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.num)

  def __repr__(self):
    return "Int4(" + self.__str__() + ")"

  def __add__(self, other): # addition
    return Int4(self.cap(self.num + other.num))

  def __sub__(self, other): # subtraction
    return Int4(self.cap(self.num - other.num))

  @staticmethod
  def cap(num): # a method that handles an overflow
    while num < 0:
      num += 16
    while num >= 16:
      num -= 16
    return num
```

And testing it:

```
>>> x,y,z = Int4(5), Int4(8), Int4(12)
>>> x
Int4(5)
>>> y
Int4(8)
>>> z
Int4(12)
>>> print x+y
13
>>> print z+y
4
>>> print x-z
9
```

Comment: Note that I used Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as clever as @martijn-pieters' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23709473/2880685), but it does seem to work on python 2.7 and 3.*, whereas I get `AttributeError: 'wrapper_descriptor' object has no attribute '__module__'` on python 2.7 with that answer.

```
import sys

lt_py3 = sys.version_info < (3,)
lt_py33 = sys.version_info < (3, 3)


class Int(int):
    '''
    int types
    '''
    def __new__(self, val=0):
        return int.__new__(self, val & (1 << self.bits - 1) - 1)

    def __max_type_bits(self, other):
        '''
        determine the largest type and bits available from those in `self` and
        `other`
        '''
        if hasattr(other, 'bits'):
            if self.bits < other.bits:
                return type(other), other.bits
        return type(self), self.bits

    def __unary_typed(oper):
        '''
        return a function that redefines the operation `oper` such that the
        result conforms to the type of `self`
        '''
        def operate(self):
            return type(self)(oper(self))
        return operate

    def __typed(oper):
        '''
        return a function that redefines the operation `oper` such that the
        result conforms to the type of `self` or `other`, whichever is larger
        if both are strongly typed (have a `bits` attribute); otherwise return
        the result conforming to the type of `self`
        '''
        def operate(self, other):
            typ, bits = self.__max_type_bits(other)
            return typ(oper(self, other))
        return operate

    def __unary_ranged(oper):
        '''
        return a function that redefines the operator `oper` such that the
        result conforms to both the range and the type of `self`
        '''
        def operate(self, other):
            '''
            type and bitmask the result to `self`
            '''
            return type(self)(oper(self) & (1 << self.bits - 1) - 1)
        return operate

    def __ranged(oper):
        '''
        return a function that redefines the operator `oper` such that the
        result conforms to both the range and the type of `self` or `other`,
        whichever is larger if both are strongly typed (have a `bits`
        attribute); otherwise return the result conforming to the type of
        `self`
        '''
        def operate(self, other):
            '''
            type and bitmask the result to either `self` or `other` whichever
            is larger
            '''
            typ, bits = self.__max_type_bits(other)
            return typ(oper(self, other) & (1 << bits - 1) - 1)
        return operate

    # bitwise operations
    __lshift__  = __ranged(int.__lshift__)
    __rlshift__ = __ranged(int.__rlshift__)
    __rshift__  = __ranged(int.__rshift__)
    __rrshift__ = __ranged(int.__rrshift__)
    __and__     = __typed(int.__and__)
    __rand__    = __typed(int.__rand__)
    __or__      = __typed(int.__or__)
    __ror__     = __typed(int.__ror__)
    __xor__     = __typed(int.__xor__)
    __rxor__    = __typed(int.__rxor__)
    __invert__  = __unary_typed(int.__invert__)

    # arithmetic operations
    if not lt_py3:
        __ceil__  = __unary_typed(int.__ceil__)
        __floor__ = __unary_typed(int.__floor__)
        __int__   = __unary_typed(int.__int__)
    __abs__       = __unary_typed(int.__abs__)
    __pos__       = __unary_typed(int.__pos__)
    __neg__       = __unary_ranged(int.__neg__)
    __add__       = __ranged(int.__add__)
    __radd__      = __ranged(int.__radd__)
    __sub__       = __ranged(int.__sub__)
    __rsub__      = __ranged(int.__rsub__)
    __mod__       = __ranged(int.__mod__)
    __rmod__      = __ranged(int.__rmod__)
    __mul__       = __ranged(int.__mul__)
    __rmul__      = __ranged(int.__rmul__)
    if lt_py3:
        __div__   = __ranged(int.__div__)
        __rdiv__  = __ranged(int.__rdiv__)
    __floordiv__  = __ranged(int.__floordiv__)
    __rfloordiv__ = __ranged(int.__rfloordiv__)
    __pow__       = __ranged(int.__pow__)
    __rpow__      = __ranged(int.__rpow__)


class Int4(Int):
    bits = 4

x, y = Int4(10), Int4(9)
print(x + y)
print(x*y)
```

Running this code in a file called `answer.py` produces

```
$ python2.7 answer.py 
3
2
$ python3.4 answer.py 
3
2
```